# Add column to tabular

Tags: r, tabular

Is it possible to add a vector as a column to a tables object created by `tabular {tables}`? For example, the following table

```
df = data.frame(group = factor(rep(c('A', 'B'), each=9)), condition=factor(rep(c('low', 'medium', 'high'), 6)), x=rnorm(18))
library('tables')
tabular(x * group ~ condition * mean, df)

       high      low      medium
   A   1.0818    0.7925   0.3255
   B   0.1312   -0.5851   0.3376
```

Now say I want to add a new column with some value computed from the data that made up the whole row, i.e. an F statistic:

```
library('plyr')
fstatistic = ddply(df, .(group), function(df.sub) summary.lm(aov(x ~ condition, df.sub))$fstatistic['value'])

  group     value
1     A 5.7021984
2     B 0.6701893
```

I want to add this as a column "F" to the far right of this table. How can I do that? To be explicit, the result should be:

```
       high      low      medium   F
   A   1.0818    0.7925   0.3255   5.7021984
   B   0.1312   -0.5851   0.3376   0.6701893
```

Or even better: F is calculated from the row in the table. Is there any way to specify a `tabular` formula in a way that makes this makes this table in one go?

Comment: Please create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059). Provide some input data and specify which package `tabular` comes from.

Comment: I have re-written the question with reproducible code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a nice way to define a function for tabular. Functions in tabular operate on individual data vectors, not whole tables, so your lm.fit won't work. Instead just do

```
tblr <- tabular(x * group ~ condition * mean, df)
tblr <- as.matrix(tblr, rowLabels=FALSE, colLabels=FALSE)
f.statistic <- ddply(df, .(group), function(df.sub) summary.lm(
      aov(x ~ condition, df.sub))$fstatistic['value'])
cbind(tblr, f.statistic)
```

Comment: Thanks, this goes a lot of the way. However, labels for rows and columns disappear with this solution. That's manageable in the case of this minimal simple two-factor table but in my actual code I have a larger table (two factors for rows and two factors for columns). Is there a way to preserve these labels?

Comment: yes, copy the row and column names over yourself using e.g. `rownames(tblr) <- whatever you want`.